# What are some healthy Indian breakfast recipes?

Tags: cooking, recipe-request

I am getting married, so I just want to know some quick and healthy Indian breakfast recipes that are vegetarian/vegan to impress my in-laws.

Comment: Congratulations! Are you looking for vegan or vegetarian recipes or both (since this site is specifically for questions about vegetarianism and veganism)? Also, since there are sooo many Indian breakfasts (for example, Shetty's Kitchen, a popular Indian YouTube channel, is currently doing a 30 day series of simple veg breakfasts), this question might be considered too broad for this platform. You may also like to come to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/the-greenhouse) to talk about this topic.

Comment: I changed the question to ask about vegetarian/vegan recipes since in the form it was originally it was not fitting for this Q&A site. Feel free to change this back if it doesn't represent your original intent.

Answer (score 5):

I like making low oil [paratha](https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-make-parathas-pan-fried-indian-flatbread-4122134) and spreading strawberry jam on top as a health substitute for a donut.  Actually, I sometimes take a bite out of the center and call it an Indian donut.

Rolling out the dough takes a little practice but you get good at it fast, the first one you fry may just be a taste tester.

Answer (score 1):

There are many recipes that you can try from Indian breakfast. But I would like to  share one that you can easily make with readily available ingredients in your country.

You just need to grate the cauliflower and mix it with some spices, salt, pepper and herbs. Roll out dough, stuff with the filling, roll again and roast. You can serve it with Greek yogurt and pickles. Cauliflower stuffed flatbread is known as  Gobi paratha in India.

You can read a simple version of this recipe [on my website](https://www.hassanchef.com/2020/02/gobi-cauliflower-paratha.html)

[image: cauliflower stuffed flatbread serving with green chutney]

Comment: Are you the owner of, or affiliated with the site you linked to? If so, you must declare your affiliation in the post. See [this page](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) of the Help Center

Comment: Yes the site belongs to me but I don't have that intention to promote the site. Actually I thought to provide the simple information about the breakfast with easy available ingredients. I am sorry if this really broke any rules.

Comment: I edited your post so that it complies with the rules, although it would be better to describe the procedure more completely in the post - making stuffed parathas is quite a skilled task imho

Comment: Thank you and noted. I will try my best to explain in future.